# tengo un error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find child entry in parent;

Tags: java

En estos momento estoy haciendo un insert en access por medio de la conexión con ucanaccess, la conexión me funciona pero el query me saca algunas excepciones, con algunos usuarios cuando los voy a insertar y esto es lo que me sale en consola:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find child entry in parent;
>   childEntry NodeEntry[rowId=400691:2,subPage=398333,bytes=(14) 7F 80 00
>   0B  E8 7F C0 E4  F4 47 A2 B3  C4 D6]; parent NodeDataPage[318587]
>   56830, 10326,
>   (299665)[entries=[NodeEntry[rowId=8497:31,subPage=57319,bytes=(14) 7F
>   80 00 0A  31 7F C0 E4  86 DA 9D 33  F5
>   61],NodeEntry[rowId=228496:40,subPage=10286,bytes=(14) 7F 80 00 0A  31
>   7F C0 E4  90 67 F9 14  19
>
> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: Could not find child entry
>   in parent;

Alguien sabe algo de ese error que me sale ?

Este es el manager en donde llamo la conexión y lo mando al DAO

```
public boolean RegistroSalida(String id)throws Exception{
    connection = ConexionAccess.getConexion();
    boolean respuesta = false;
    try {
        objDAO = new LectorDAO();
        respuesta = objDAO.RegistroSalida(id,connection);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    //connection.close();
    return respuesta;
}
```

acá es donde hago la el insert que lo hago en el DAO

```
public boolean RegistroSalida(String id, Connection conexion) throws Exception{
        boolean respuesta = false;
        try {
            String query = "INSERT INTO checkinout (USERID,CHECKTIME,CHECKTYPE,VERIFYCODE,SENSORID,Memoinfo,WorkCode,sn,UserExtFmt) "
                    + " SELECT USERINFO.USERID, now(), 'I', 3, '107', '', 0 , '' , 1 "
                    + " FROM USERINFO" + " WHERE (((USERINFO.[SSN])='"+ id +"'));";

            PreparedStatement ps = conexion.prepareStatement(query);
            System.out.println(query);
            if (ps.executeUpdate() >= 0)
                respuesta = true;
                System.out.println("oK");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("Paila");
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
```

Esta es la conexión con la base de dato Access:

public class ConexionAccess {
    private static Connection cn = null;

```
public static Connection getConexion() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/attBackup01042015.mdb;memory=true");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cn;
}
```

}

Comment: Veo un insert y un select juntos, perdona mi ignorancia pero en el query estas ingresando valores o los estas retornando?

Comment: pues con el select estoy consultando un dato en especifico y lo guardo con el insert, lo que hace ese query es buscar el ID que tiene el usuario por defecto en el lector por medio de la cedula

Comment: Pero lo que tu estas haciendo es concatenar todo junto; ya intentaste ejecutar la query sola?

Comment: si claro, y me funciona dentro de la base de datos, pero cuando lo ejecuto en la aplicación, solo con algunos usuarios me sale error, el resto me los deja insertar y como en programación una aplicación sirve o no sirve :/

Comment: Y por que ejecutas un execute update cuando puedes ejecutar un execute query, segun veo no estas haciendo update, y si haces un select deberias de recorrer el resultado, tampoco veo los valores que dices intentas ingresar

Comment: El unico valor que intento insertar es el ID que tiene por defecto cada uno de los usuarios y con la cedula el SELECT me lo retorna, también ensaye lo que usted me dice y tampoco, me sale el mismo error  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find child entry in parent; childEntry ...

Comment: Intenta revisando estos ejemplos que son muy buenos y te pueden ser de ayuda https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd776381(v=sql.105).aspx#OtherTables

Comment: es que el Query que tengo me funciona y la de los ejemplos también pero todavía me saca la exception al insertar algún usuario, porque de 10 usuario que intento insertar hay 2 que no me deja insertar :/